# Changing a folder in a path for writing using re and glob libraries

Tags: python, jython, glob, python-re, jython-2.5

I have two directories: `path/to/folder` and `path/to/otherfolder` which both have several sub-directories inside them: `path/to/folder/TEST1`, `path/to/folder/TEST2`, `path/to/otherfolder/TEST1`, `path/to/otherfolder/TEST2`, etc.

I'm getting all the subdirectories in the root folder using `folder_path = glob.glob('path/to/folder/*')`

I then loop over each sub-directory to get all the files in them:

```
for folder in folder_path:
    file_path = glob.glob(folder + '\*')
    for files in file_path:
        new_path = files.replace('folder', 'otherfolder')
        with open(files, r) as f:
            with open(new_path, 'wb') as wf:
                do stuff
```

This isn't working though as no files are being written to. I thought about simply changing this line to `files.replace('\\folder\\', '\\otherfolder\\')` but I don't think this will work.

I'd like to use Python's `re` library if anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the glob pattern. Instead of:

```
    file_path = glob.glob(folder + '\*')
```

can you try

```
    file_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*'))
```

?

This will require you to `import os` at the top of your file.

---

There is also a syntax error here:

```
        with open(files, r) as f:
```

Should be:

```
        with open(files, 'r') as f:
```

Comment: still isn't writing to the file